# Comparator Won't Work

Tags: java, arrays, collections, comparator

```
public class Test implements Comparable <Test>{
String name;
int age;
int salary;
public Test(String name, int age, int salary){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.salary = salary;
}
public int compareTo(Test newTest){
    if (this.name.compareTo(newTest.name) > 0){
        return 1;
    } else if(this.name.compareTo(newTest.name) < 0){
        return -1;
    } else{
        return 0;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Test Albert = new Test("Albert", 19, 100);
    Test James = new Test("James", 16, 50);
    if (Albert.compareTo(James) == -1){
        System.out.println("Albert Comes first");
    } else if (Albert.compareTo(James) == 1){
        System.out.println("James Comes first");
    } else{
        System.out.println("It's a tie");
    }

    int[] testArray = new int[2];
    testArray[0] = Albert.age;
    testArray[1] = James.age;

    Collections.sort(testArray, new TestComparator());
}
}
```

I've created a comparator called TestComparator and for some reason it won't work with Collections.sort. I'm not sure why its not working. Any ideas? I also tried Array.sort which didn't work. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the code for `TestComparator`? Also, try to specify what is the output you're getting now and what's the expected output.

Comment: `Test.compareTo()` should simply return `name.compareTo(newTest.name)`.  It certainly shouldn't call `name.compareTo()` twice.

Comment: @aaa I just updated my answer to include both sort by name and sort by age, both with a list of `Test` objects.  Have a look and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.sort()` works with a `List<Integer>`, not an array.

`Arrays.sort()` only works with an `int[]` if you want ascending order.

Change the array to be of type `Integer[]` and you should be able to use the version of `Arrays.sort()` that uses a `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

For above program. you just need to use Arrays.sort(testArray);

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Test Albert = new Test("Albert", 19, 100);
    Test James = new Test("James", 16, 50);

    if (Albert.compareTo(James) == -1){
        System.out.println("Albert Comes first");
    } else if (Albert.compareTo(James) == 1){
        System.out.println("James Comes first");
    } else{
        System.out.println("It's a tie");
    }

    int[] testArray = new int[2];
    testArray[0] = Albert.age;
    testArray[1] = James.age;

    Arrays.sort(testArray); //You are just using int array so no need of Collections.sort

    for(int temp: testArray){
           System.out.println("Age :: " + temp); 
    }
    //Collections.sort(testArray, new );
}
}
```

If you want to sorting on object then you have to use comparable interface  and that will sort based on what you have implemented inside override compareTo method.

you can have better idea about comprable and comparaor from below links.
[Java Object Sorting Example (Comparable And Comparator)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Answer (score 0):

Line of code

```
Collections.sort(testArray, new TestComparator());
```

should be throwing compilation error, since there is no such sort method in Collections class.

Use `Arrays.sort(testArray)`, instead; which will sort the array in Ascending order.

BTW, what are you trying to do by passing a TestComparator for a array of premitives?